# What does it mean if a method returns browser.page?

Tags: selenium, geb

I wanted to start practicing some more of GEB/selenium best practices.

I found some documentation that I am trying to mimic but I am not getting the desired result and I believe it may be do to my misunderstanding.

I found this code snippet [here](https://objectpartners.com/2013/09/12/type-safe-page-objects-with-geb/):

```java
class HomePage extends geb.Page {
  static content = {
    loginLink(to: LoginPage) { $("#login_link") }
  }

  LoginPage clickLoginLink() {
    loginLink.click()

    return browser.page
  }
}
```

```java
class LoginPage extends geb.Page {
  static content = {
    usernameField { $("#username") }
    passwordField { $("#password") }
    loginButton(to: DashboardPage) { $("#login_button") }  
  }

  DashboardPage login(String username, String password) {
    usernameField.value(username)  
    passwordField.value(password)
    loginButton.click()

    return browser.page
  }
}
```

It then goes on to say that this structure allows you to make this call:

```
DashboardPage dashboardPage = to(HomePage).clickLoginLink().login('user1', 'password1')
```

I have tried to set up something slightly similar the code is as follows:

Page:

```java
class LoginPage extends Page {

    static at = { $(By.xpath("//h1[text()='Welcome to Your Company JIRA']")).displayed }
    static url = "http://localhost:2990/jira/login.jsp"

    static content = {
        LOGIN_USER {$(By.id("login-form-username"))}
        LOGIN_PASS  {$(By.id("login-form-password"))}
        LOGIN_BTN  (to: SystemDashboardPage, toWait:10)  {$(By.id("login-form-submit"))}
        banner {module JiraBanner}
    }

    def logIn(user, pass){
        LOGIN_USER.value(user)
        LOGIN_PASS.value(pass)
        LOGIN_BTN.click()
        return browser.page
    }

}
```

Script:

```java
class Test extends GebReportingSpec {

    //The Pages we will use for this test
    @Shared
    def loginPage = new LoginPage()
    def systemDashboardPage = new SystemDashboardPage()

    def "Login to Jira"(){
        when: "we navigate to Jira Login"
        loginPage = to LoginPage
        and: "we login"
        systemDashboardPage = loginPage.logIn("admin", "admin")
        then: "We should be at the home page"
        assert systemDashboardPage instanceof SystemDashboardPage
    }
}

def "Navigate to Issues Admin Page"(){
    when: "we Navigate to the Admin Issues Page"
    issuesAdminsPage = systemDashboardPage.banner.goToIssuesAdmin()
    then: "we should be at the issue admin Page"
    assert issuesAdminsPage instanceof IssuesAdminPage
}
```

When I run this code though I get:

```
Instance of page class Pages.SystemDashboardPage has not been initialized. 
Please pass it to Browser.to(), Browser.via(), Browser.page() or 
Browser.at() before using it.
geb.error.PageInstanceNotInitializedException: Instance of page class 
Pages.SystemDashboardPage has not been initialized. Please pass it to 
Browser.to(), Browser.via(), Browser.page() or Browser.at() before using it.
```

From what I can understand from the example, returning browser.page should be initializing the page since I added the `to` flag to the static content.

What am I missing here?

Comment: When asking questions it makes sense to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You are using classes in your code such as `DashboardPage`, `SystemDashboardPage` and `IssuesAdminPage`, but not sharing them here. And why are you calling page constructors manually? What are you trying to achieve there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set the global variables under `@Shared` in the test script to `static` which is actually counter intuitive if you ask me.

So instead of

```
def loginPage = new LoginPage()
def systemDashboardPage = new SystemDashboardPage()
```

I needed to put

```
static loginPage = new LoginPage()
static systemDashboardPage = new SystemDashboardPage()
```

you can't dynamically change the global variables without casting them as static.......

Comment: If you answer your own question, please do so in a way others can understand. Which "global variables" are you talking about?